# Populating Select Element using PHP, SQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

So I have this form below in a html file named searchform.html
  There are three search elements a *Title* search field using text input, a *Year* Number element and a *Publisher* select element.

```
        <form id = "SearchForm" method = "get">
        <form action="searchget.php" method="get">

            <p>CD Title</p>
            <input type = "search" name = "title" /><br>
            <p>CD Publisher</p>
            <select name="publisher">
                <?php include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection
                $sql = "SELECT pubName FROM `nmc_cd`
                    INNER JOIN nmc_category
                    ON nmc_category.catID = nmc_cd.catID
                    INNER JOIN nmc_publisher
                    ON nmc_publisher.pubID = nmc_cd.pubID";

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo "<option value=\"publisher\">" . $row['pubName'] . "</option>";} ?>
            </select><br>
            <p>CD Year</p>
            <input type = "number" name = "year" />
            <input type = "submit" value = "Search" />
        </form>
```

All of the elements have been named such as name="title" and the title and year elements entered are appearing in the search URL. However the select is not and its also not populating from my database.

```
<?php  include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection

        $pCDTitle = $_GET['title'];
        $pCDYear = $_GET['year'];
        $hPub = $_GET['publisher'];

    $sql = "SELECT pubName, CDYear, CDTitle 
    FROM `nmc_cd`
    INNER JOIN nmc_category
    ON nmc_category.catID = nmc_cd.catID
    INNER JOIN nmc_publisher
    ON nmc_publisher.pubID = nmc_cd.pubID
    WHERE CDTitle = '$pCDTitle' AND CDYear = '$pCDYear' AND pubName <= '$hPub'";

        $rsCD = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCD)) {
              $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
              $CDYear = $row['CDYear']; 
              $pubName = $row['publisher']; 
        }
              mysqli_free_result($rsCD);
          mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

I am quite new to PHP and can't figure out whats going wrong here I was taught this recently and struggled with this part of the form

```
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     echo "<option value=\"publisher\">" . $row['pubName'] . "
```

Comment: why is this in there `<form id = "SearchForm" method = "get"` and with a missing `>`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo transferring code across it is in final version

Comment: you're also mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` and those do not intermix and nested forms. probably the main reason here.

Comment: I think this may be because the person that taught me the select population part of this was a completely different person that I haven't had help off before, if possible could you point this out.

Comment: this `mysql_fetch_array` must read as `mysqli_fetch_array` and make sure that you are indeed using `mysqli_` to connect with; that's unknown.

Comment: I remember this being due to the injection protection correct ?

Comment: that has nothing to do with that.

Comment: okay no bother thank you anyway.

Comment: Ive checked my connection file and it is indeed  `mysqli_connect`

Comment: Chiefly missing here is a call to `mysqli_query()` to actually execute the query.  You are using the variable `$sql` which is the SQL string variable in `mysql_fetch_array()` here `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){`.  You must first call `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` and then pass `$result` into `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` rather than `$sql`. (note that's `mysqli_` not `mysql_`)

Comment: also, your publisher select needs to be updated so that the value attribute of each option is unique, either use the pubID or pubName, otherwise, no matter what the user selects, its value will always be "publisher"

Comment: Okay thanks to Michael I have the select populated although it has some duplicate results but I have found a way to get around that. I have al;so changed the value to pubName as you suggested. This all started to make a lot of sense after i looked into the actual query I wanted to run a lot more. Michael if you'd like to post your response as an answer i'll happily mark this answered by you.